Browser shows SSL notification to choose for authentication
I have configured SSL for ELB with a custom domain using AWS ACM. Some browsers access domain that have a notification to choose SSL cert as image 
But some browsers access normally. This is the first time I have seen this issue. Can everyone explain for me and how to resolve it? Thanks
